# Selecting data from multiple tables(Laravel)

Tags: sql, laravel

This getproduct() function is giving me output only when there is is records in all three tables for `$product_id` How can i get output even when one or two of the table doesnot have any record for `$product_id`

```
        $currUser = Auth::User();
        ### search
        //$output_product = $currUser->products()->where('product_id', $product_id)->first();
        $output_product = DB::table('products')
            ->select('products.title', 'products.description', 'product_variants.price', 'product_variants.quantity', 'products.product_id', 'product_images.imgurl')
            ->join('product_variants', 'products.product_id', '=', 'product_variants.product_id')
            ->join('product_images', 'product_variants.id', '=', 'product_images.variant_id')
            ->where('products.product_id', $product_id)
            ->get();
        return $output_product;
                        
        }
```

Comment: you should read about join left/right https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins

Comment: You can try left join.

Comment: @HafijurRahman Left join has a chance to display identical records if there are two matching records present on another table. Good for 1 to 1 relationship but not good for 1  to many

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `DB::raw` for that.

First you need to specify your main table which is `products`.

You'll then have to remove the two joins you have from the query and state them in `DB::raw` in `select()` function.

For example:

```
$output_product = DB::table('products')
                    ->select('products.title', 'products.description', 'product_variants.price', 'product_variants.quantity', 'products.product_id', 'product_images.imgurl', DB::raw('YOUR SELECT STATEMENT HERE'))
                    ->where('products.product_id', $product_id)
                    ->get();
```

Note that `DB::raw` will only get one column so you'll have to use multiple DB::raw()'s for each data you want.

Another solution is to get only the `products` table then create another function to call the other tables.

You will have to pass it to your blade and then use `@forelse` there.

For example

```
@forelse($product as $p)
      @forelse($productvariant->where('product_id', $p->id) as $variant)

      @empty
       // This section will display if there are no results
      @endforelse
@empty

@endforelse
```

As such, this will display your products even without the other 2 tables having a matching record